# How to build and run a Docker image in a scripted Jenkinsfile pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build and run a docker image on a specific build node from a scripted Jenkinsfile. Switching to declarative syntax is something I would rather like to avoid.
My code is quite close to the example from the [documentation](https://tempora-mutantur.github.io/jenkins.io/github_pages_test/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers). The image builds as expected. But running the container fails Jenkins complaining the physical machine of the node is not running inside a container and the echo and make commands from the innermost block that I would expect to run inside the container are not executed and do not appear in the log.

As far as I understand Jenkins considers containers to be build nodes on their own and that nesting of node statements are not allowed. At the same time a node is required to build and run the Docker image.

What am I missing to build and run the image? As Im quite new to Jenkins as well as to Docker any hints or recommendations are appreciated.

The code:

```
node('BuildMachine1')
{
    withEnv(envList)
    {
        dir("/some/path")
        {
            docker.build("build-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ${env.WORKSPACE}/build/Dockerfile .").inside
            {
                echo "Echo from Docker"
                sh script: 'make'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The log:

```
Successfully built 8c57cad188ed
Successfully tagged build-image:79
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . build-image:79
.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
BuildMachine1 does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1004:1005 -w /data/Jenkins_Node/workspace/myFeature/buildaarch64Release -v /data/Jenkins_Node/workspace/myFeature/buildaarch64Release:/data/Jenkins_Node/workspace/myFeature/buildaarch64Release:rw,z -v /data/Jenkins_Node/workspace/myFeature/buildaarch64Release@tmp:/data/Jenkins_Node/workspace/myFeature/buildaarch64Release@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** build-image:87 cat
$ docker top 2242078968bc1ee5ddfd08c73a2e1551eda36c2595f0e4c9fb6e9b3b0af15b8b -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
```

Comment: According to the logs everything is successful. Also, the logs match the expected behavior of the code. Could you please clarify what is different between your expectations and the code/logs?

Comment: It seems the docker run command or the execution of Jenkins stuff inside the container is failing. The echo and make commands are not executed, or at least not logged.

Comment: You could try logging into the node host manually and running the `docker logs` command against the container that Jenkins created.  My guess is either the container is exiting prematurely based on the content of your Dockerfile or the way your command line is configured in the container isn't printing output to stdout. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Entrypoint of the container was configured in a way that worked for manual usage in terminal but not inside the Jenkins pipeline.
It was set as
`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env", "bash"]`
After changing it to
`ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]`
the resulting container is used by the Jenkinsfile as intended.